# Having problem passing member function pointers to templatized member function on gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, pointer-to-member

I'm having problem passing member function pointers to templatized member function on gcc.  Does anyone know how to modify the code below to get gcc to accept what I am trying to do?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template <class C, class R>
    void Execute(R(typename C::*memFn)())
    {
    }
};
```

I get the following errors when trying to compile the code:

```
test.cpp:40: error: 'memFn' was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:40: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
test.cpp:40: error: expected identifier before '*' token
test.cpp:40: error: expected '(' before '*' token
test.cpp:40: error: 'memFn' was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:40: error: variable or field 'Execute' declared void
```

The version of gcc that I am using is 4.4.2.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `typename`. Remove that and it should work. (I tested it on gcc 4.3.2).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I originally put it in there.  Of course MSVS doesn't care. <sigh>